# Include link in form label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to include a link in a form label as such:

```
<%= form.check_box 'eula' %>
<%= form.label 'eula', "I agree to the <a href='#' id='eula-link'>EULA</a>", class: 'label-checkbox' %>
```

Rails writes the HTML out, as it probably should, but how would I accomplish this? Clicking EULA opens a JS popup. I was thinking of embedding a link_to in there somehow ?

Comment: You just have to use the `link_to` helper in the form label string, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `html_safe` with parens will render the html, like so:

```
<%= f.input :eula, :as => :boolean, label: ("I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', terms_path}.").html_safe %>
```

Comment: I believe you're supposed to use `sanitize` instead of `html_safe`

Comment: How would you add a FontAwesome icon in the `link_to`?

Comment: `label: sanitize("I agree to the #{link_to((fa_icon('check') + ' Terms and Conditions'), terms_and_conditions_path, target: '_blank')}.", tags: %w(a i), attributes: %w(href target class))`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using vanilla rails form helpers, you can do this:

```
f.label :eula do
    'I agree to the #{link_to("EULA", "#")}'
end
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label

Answer (score 1):

19 ways tried, with either the hyperlink being encoded or html_safe replacing hyphens in the url ???

This is what worked for me

```
<%= f.label :cookies do
      "Do you agree to our #{link_to('Cookies Policy', 'http://www.your-­url.co.uk/privacypolicy')}".html_safe
end %>
```

The specific use of " and ' appears significant.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from jenson-button-event *nearly* worked for me, but required a change in the placement of a parenthesis close to load without errors.

For me the below solved it. Note the close-bracket after 'Cookies Policy' here, rather than after the link path itself.

```
<%= f.label :cookies do
      "Do you agree to our #{link_to('Cookies Policy'), 'http://www.your-­ url.co.uk/privacypolicy'}".html_safe
end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try "I agree to the #{link_to 'EULA', #, :id => 'eula-link'}"

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a simple way to add a font awesome help link button after the form field label, this is what I used in my haml file:

```
    = form_for [@preplan, @structure] do |f|
      = f.label :template do
        Template
        = link_to 'https://intercom.help/blazemark/preplans-and-structures/structure-templates', target: '_blank' do
          = fa_icon 'fw info-circle'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of rails 6.0.2.1 (January 2020), this is what worked for me:

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
  <%= form.check_box :accept_terms, class: "form-check-input", required: true %>
  <%= form.label :accept_terms, class: "form-check-label" do %>
    <span>
      Accept <%= link_to 'Terms and Conditions', 'https://your.url.here.com' %>
    </span>
  <% end %>
</div>
```